# Removing node by name in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I cannot seem to manage removing sub-nodes from a YAML node using the YAML-cpp library. This is the code I'm trying:

```
  YAML::Node y = YAML::Load("\
  a: first\n\
  b: second\n\
  c: \n\
      d: third\n\
      e: \n\
          f: fourth\n\
          g: fifth\n\
  ");  
  cout << y;
  cout << endl << endl;
  y.remove(y["b"]);
  cout << y;
  cout << endl;
```

and this is the output:

```
a: first
c:
  e:
    g: fifth
    f: fourth
  d: third
b: second

a: first
c:
  e:
    g: fifth
    f: fourth
  d: third
b: second
```

while the expected output should be that the second emitted YAML stream doesn't contain the "b" element.

What am I missing here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that node.remove() is broken in yaml-cpp 0.5.2, which is the current version on Ubuntu Xenial and many other distros.
(https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/338)

The code should look like this:

```
YAML::Node y = YAML::Load("\
a: first\n\
b: second\n\
c: \n\
  d: third\n\
  e: \n\
      f: fourth\n\
      g: fifth\n\
");  
cout << y;
cout << endl << endl;
y.remove("b");
cout << y;
cout << endl;
```

so the correct parameter for `remove` is a string (given that I'm removing from a map), which originally didn't compile:

```
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:392:58:   required from ‘bool    YAML::Node::remove(const Key&) [with Key = char [2]]’
/turbine/turbine/src/components/yaml-test.cpp:51:15:   required from here
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:136:15: error: ‘equals’ was not declared in this scope
 if (equals(*it->first, key, pMemory)) {
...
```

but works fine in 0.5.3.