# Remove data from YAML file in cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have data base:

```yaml
point:
  A:
    w: 0.922068417
    x: -1.89226389
    y: -0.992412388
    z: -0.387026489
  B:
    w: 0.922068417
    x: -1.89226389
    y: -0.992412388
    z: -0.387026489
  a:
    x: -1.5980000000000001
    y: -0.40000000000000002
    z: 1
    w: 0.029999999999999999
```

When i want to remom point A in data, i haved tried many differennt way but it didn't work.

```cpp
void delete_point(string name)
{
 // Open File YAML 
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("../nodes/cpp_data.yaml");
    ofstream fout("../nodes/cpp_data.yaml");
    
    config.remove(config["point"][name]);
    // or use line code
    config["point"].remove(config["point"][name]);
    cout<< config["point"];
    // Save File YAML
    fout << config;
    fout.close();

    ROS_INFO("DONE DELETE POINT");
}
```

But when i save data ,it is successful
What is this bug??

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: code is running successfull but data don't detete ,data is unchanged

Comment: I'm going to guess you are using yaml-cpp? It doesn't seem to have much in the way of documentation but going by the [unit tests](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/328d2d85e833be7cb5a0ab246cc3f5d7e16fc67a/test/node/node_test.cpp#L186) you need `config["point"].remove(name)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453826/removing-node-by-name-in-yaml-cpp

Comment: Yeahhh, this is successful, thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).